# Почему стоит запятая перед одиночным союзом И? Это частный случай для однородных сказуемых?

Tags: запятые, и

Это текст: *На переменке сбегаю, отдам, решил Ластик и сунул бутылку в портфель. Припустил по переулку со всех ног. Уже ясно было, что к звонку не успеет, но это еще полбеды. Ровно в 8.35 к дверям школы выходит сама Раиса Петровна, завуч. **Встает у входа, и всем злостным нарушителям дисциплины (это которые опоздали больше чем на пять минут) лично пишет замечание в дневник.** Вот уж чего не хотелось бы*   (Б. Акунин).

Почему стоит запятая перед одиночным союзом И? Также интересно, какая здесь грамматика.

Спасибо.

Comment: Здесь присоединение. Здесь нет одновременных действий.

Comment: Одновременность действий – это не показатель для присоединительных конструкций (по Розенталю). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

Comment: Вы не поняли. Если  было бы одновременность действий, не было бы запятой.

Comment: Я в общем случае говорю, что для присоединительных конструкций важны  другие факторы, а не время действия. Присоединительные члены предложения содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания. Здесь вторая часть – это основное содержание предложения, а не дополнительное.

Comment: @Серж ‟Я открыл дверь и вышел на улицу” – здесь что, присоединение из-за неодновременности? ‟Я вышел из дома и спустя час пил пиво в баре” – здесь что, присоединение из-за неодновременности?

Answer (score 0):

Запятая стоит по причине ошибки. Между однородными с одиночным ‟и” может стоять запятая только по причине присоединения, что невозможно в такой ситуации. Присоединение с одиночным ‟и” возможно только тогда, когда человек задумывает предложение без второго однородного, а решает добавить его только по ходу произношения, а это предложение нельзя было задумать без второго однородного.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, но эта книга переиздавалась много раз, так что ошибка исключается. Это авторский знак, и его нужно понять и объяснить.

Comment: А что такое авторский знак?

Comment: Там возможны варианты, лучше посмотреть тему у Розенталя http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=197#pp197

Comment: Если взять всех лингвистов и убрать тупых и сумасшедших, то останется 5 человек. Этим объясняются все эти авторские пунктуации и тому подобная шиза.

Comment: Все редакторы просто думали следующее: ‟А что если я уберу эту запятую, которую многие другие не убрали, а другие сочтут, что я недостаточно знаю авторское конфу, поэтому лучше я оставлю эту запятую. Мне нужно скрывать, что я ничего не понимаю про авторскую пунктуацию, нельзя себя выдать. Господи, помоги мне”.